# Making 'sitemap.xml' inaccessible to users but accessible to bots

Tags: php, iis-7, seo, sitemap, web-config

I'm using PHP and IIS 7 on windows server. I have created a sitemap `sitemap.xml` in root folder of my site.

But it can be easily seen by the user using browser and GET request.

So my Question is How to make it inaccessible to users but still accessible to crawlers of search engines.

for example: https://stackoverflow.com/sitemap.xml is inaccessible to users, but still it gets inlisted in googles search, and it is there (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22308/stack-overflow-sitemap-wtf).

How do they do it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't understand, why it is necessary.

You could do this by checking the useragent. But you have to know that the user can set his own user agent to a useragent which is used by Google and the other search engines.

Comment: it is necessary to ensure that only search engines crawls your pages and to tell Google about pages on the site which might not otherwise discovered.

Comment: Why is it a problem if the user can access the sitemap?

Comment: 1. An xml file doesn't have a size of several GB's usually. 2. Every user can change the useragent and then you can't see if this is really a search engine. 3. You have to allow every little search engine and there are many search engines.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/sitemap.xml. Page Not Found. There should be a good reason why it is necessary while the sitemap location is valid per the [robots.txt](http://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt)

Answer (score 1):

You could give your `sitemap.xml` a hard to guess name such as `tt44DM-09.xml`. Then you could submit it to search engines through their Webmaster interface. Of course, you should not declare your sitemap in your `robots.txt`.

It is not a perfect solution, but it is easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

As jan said, just don't do it. There's no reason for such thing. It's called cloaking, and it can harm your website.

Comment: exact term is `cloaking`, +1 for that, That's It. Thanks a lot.